# Determine if string ends in whitespace and append a space if not

Tags: regex, r

I would like to check if a string ends with a whitespace. If it doesn't I would like to add a trailing space character to the end of the string.

Actually, I check if the string ends with a whitespace with `grepl` and then I `paste` a space at the end.

```
append_space <- function(x) {
  if(!grepl("(\\s)$", x))
    x <- paste0(x, " ")
  return(x)
}
```

However, I think I can do that directly with the `sub` function, with a negative lookahead using `!` but I don't know how to use it.

Does anyone know how I can do it with `sub`?

Comment: You function seems to append a space regardless of the end of the string. `> sub("(.*[^\\s])", "\\1 ", "string")
[1] "string "
> sub("(.*[^\\s])", "\\1 ", "string ")
[1] "string  "
> sub("(.*[^\\s])", "\\1 ", "string\n")
[1] "string\n "`

Comment: that was because I forgot the `$` in the comment, I posted an answer, where I did put a `$`, after testing my regex... actually, you're right, there is a bug even with the $ :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `sub` with capturing group and a backreference in the replacement part:

```
sub("(\\S)$", "\\1 ", x)
```

`\S` means `non-whitespace`.

See [demo](https://ideone.com/xyshag)

Comment: I don't think `perl=TRUE` is necessary here (+1)

Comment: @BrodieG: True, I just feel more comfortable using Perl flavor.

Comment: In my opinion, `perl = TRUE` should really be the default in the R regex functions.

Comment: @AlexA., I agree, especially since TRE has some bugs.

Answer (score 11):

You may also try

```
 sub(' ?$', ' ', x)
 #[1] "blabla1 " "blabla2 "
```

where

```
 x <- c("blabla1 ", "blabla2")
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this approach would work:

```
x <- c("blabla1 ","blabla2")

sub("(?<=([^ ])$)$", " ", x, perl=TRUE)
## [1] "blabla1 " "blabla2 "
```

Answer (score 4):

Like I said in my comment, you can try:

```
sub("(.*[^ ])$","\\1 ", x)
```

**Example**

```
x <- c("blabla1 ","blabla2")
sub("(.[^ ])$","\\1 ", x)
#[1] "blabla1 " "blabla2 "
```

Comment: @AlexA. apparently  [^\\s] doesn't work to negate the space, so one has to put \\S instead

Comment: your function works if you replace brackets by parenthesis : `sub("(.*(^\\s))$", "X", " string\n a a")` but I don't know the difference.

Comment: @JulienNavarre, just using the actual space (` `) works actually, sometimes there is no need to complicate things after all ;-)